# replace color in imageData failure

Tags: javascript, canvas

i have this script.

```
var oriToCopy = function(){
    while(pps.length > 0){
        var pp = pps.pop();
        layerDataCopy.data[pp] = layerDataOri.data[pp];
        layerDataCopy.data[pp + 1] = layerDataOri.data[pp + 1];
        layerDataCopy.data[pp + 2] = layerDataOri.data[pp + 2];
    }
    ctxCopy.putImageData(layerDataCopy, 0, 0);
}
```

where : 
pps is array of pixel position in the canvas
layerDataOri is imageData from Original canvas
layerDataCopy is imageData from Copy canvas

what i am trying to do is to copy layerDataOri at `layerDataOri.data[pps]` to `layerDataCopy.data[pps]`. i have check that pixel at `pps` position is not a transparent pixel, but when copy this pixel to `layerDataCopy` it's not affected, the copy canvas is still transparent.

what is wrong?

Comment: How do you get the copy buffer, using createImageData or getImageData?

Comment: for both `ori` and `copy` i use getImageData.

Comment: For performances : 1) Don't forget to cache locally layerDataCopy.data and layerDataOri.data for a speed boost (var copyData=layerDataOri.data; ... ) . And 2) if the data is a Uint8ClampedArray (it might be a CanvasPixelArray on some browsers) you can use 32 bits views on the buffers to copy 4 times faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you also copy the alpha channel as each pixels consist of four channels (RGBA):

```
layerDataCopy.data[pp] = layerDataOri.data[pp];
layerDataCopy.data[pp + 1] = layerDataOri.data[pp + 1];
layerDataCopy.data[pp + 2] = layerDataOri.data[pp + 2];
layerDataCopy.data[pp + 3] = layerDataOri.data[pp + 3]; // alpha
```

Note that pp must also be quantized by 4 to point to a valid pixel (you're now showing how you generate the positions in the question, so just in case).

If the canvas you're getting the copy buffer from is blank (nothing drawn into it) all pixels will be transparent by default. So when, during the copy, the alpha channel isn't copied over the pixel will remain transparent.

You could also use `createImageData` instead of `getImageData` for the copy buffer if it isn't containing any data in advance (it's faster).

Comment: yes, it's already grouped by 4. the pps is pixel that generated by paint bucket, and from this pps i want to get the pixel from `ori` canvas and copy it in `copy` canvas

Comment: @DarielPratama if you don't get it to work using this answer then please set up a fiddle for us so we can dig a bit deeper into the problem.

Comment: ok, wait i will push it to my own server. too complex to put it in fiddle

Comment: please see this, http://comicedu.com/htmlcropper/v1 <br>
klik browse file on top right and then start making closed path using paint brush, and fill that closed path using paint bucket.

Comment: by the way, you are right @Epistemex, the alpha channel is 0 in `copy` canvas so that i assign the alpha channel to `255` so it is now `layerDataCopy.data[pp + 3] = 255;`